# Different domain and url shortener for asp.net mvc app

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I would like to implement a simple URL shortener feature like Bitly.

My Controller name: **WebController**

My Action name: **Redirect**

As the name suggests the action redirects the user from the short URL to the full URL.

To call this action I need: https://myappdomain.com/web/redirect?id=3422

But I would like to be able to call this feature in a much shorter way with a different (shorter) domain and without the need to call the action name: https://shorterdomain.com/3422

Can you guide me how can I do this? I am a bit lost even for what to search for:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a route to the shorter URL so MVC knows what controller and action will handle the request. Something like this:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(name: "redirection",
                pattern: "{id:int}",
                defaults: new { controller = "web", action = "redirect" });

    ... your existing routes
});
```

Comment: Thanks! How about the fact that I would like to use a different domain for this (than the one from the app)? Can you help me?

Comment: To use a different domain, you can set a binding in IIS so that both domains point to your web application. This would allow people to access your site using either domain though. To restrict a route to a specific domain, add `.RequireHost("shorterdomain.com");` after the MapControllerRoute() call.

Comment: Here is a link that shows how to restrict a route by host. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-5.0#host-matching-in-routes-with-requirehost